# "mapper_parsing_exception" error from Elasticsearch failing to parse [timestamp] from %{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}

Tags: logging, httpd, elasticsearch, logstash, filter

I've configured Logstash to filter `httpd_access_log` messages and grok the fields associated with `COMBINEDAPACHELOG`. However, I'm receiving errors like the following:

```
[2017-02-10T15:37:39,361][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed action. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"filebeats", :_type=>"logs", :_routing=>nil}, 2017-02-10T23:37:34.187Z perf-wuivcx02.hq.mycompany.com cdn.mycompany.com 192.168.222.60 - - [10/Feb/2017:15:37:30 -0800] "GET /client/asd-client-main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 221430 "http://perf.companysite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"filebeats", "_type"=>"logs", "_id"=>"AVoqY6qkpAiTDgWeyMHJ", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [timestamp]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"number_format_exception", "reason"=>"For input string: \"10/Feb/2017:15:37:30 -0800\""}}}}}
```

Here is my Logstash filter configuration:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "json" {
    json {
      source => "message"
    }
  }
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
  if [type] == "httpd_access_log" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{URIHOST} %{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", "MMM  d yyyy HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601" ]
    }
  }
}
```

The `date` function works fine for processing `syslog` type messages, but is not working for `httpd_access_log` messages. Does anyone know why the timestamps are causing lines from `httpd_access_log` files to fail indexing in Elasticsearch?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't 100% a filter problem, the output is merely the symptom. Here are the key parts of the error message that show you this.

```
[2017-02-10T15:37:39,361][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
```

That's telling you that the plugin that failed, was the elasticsearch output.

```
Failed action. {:status=>400, :action=>["index",
```

(Clipped for clarity) That's attempting an `index` action on ElasticSearch.

```
"error"=>
  {"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception",
   "reason"=>"failed to parse [timestamp]",
   "caused_by"=>
     {"type"=>"number_format_exception",
      "reason"=>"For input string: \"10/Feb/2017:15:37:30 -0800\""}
     }
   }
```

What's happening here is that the `timestamp` field in the index is not accepting the string you're attempting to put into it. The fact that it says `number_format_exception` says that ElasticSearch is expecting a non-string as input.

Logstash is attempting to write a string to the `timestamp` field. This is a sign that the `timestamp` field hasn't actually been run through the `date {}` filter. This suggests that `if [type] == "httpd_access_log" {` isn't catching all possible instances of `timestamp`, or the pattern for your date filter isn't catching this. The error string was cleaned up, but I'm not sure if your source really is issuing a timestamp like:

```
10/Feb/2017:15:37:30 -0800
```

If it actually is entering the pipeline like that, figure out why.